# How to get block info (e.g. block hash code) in smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, wasm-api

I want to use action context information, such as block hash code, to generate number as "random" numbers in smart contract.

But I can't find any interface to get block hash code.

Comment: If you are looking to generate random numbers in your smart contract, take a look at this discussion: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/41/how-can-i-generate-random-numbers-inside-a-smart-contract

Comment: @JohnHaager  thank you so much for the link, the discussion is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block information isn't directly available. These two functions provide information from a user-selected previous block:

`int tapos_block_num();
int tapos_block_prefix();`

There are a couple problems with relying on these:

- They are from a block in the past
- The person who created the transaction filled these by selecting a block and copying the values

Comment: Thank you! Now I can get the block number and then save to table. My App can fetch the block number and then get the subsequent 15 (or more) blocks' information.  I have another quesiton: What's the meaning of block prefix? What's it for?