# Transaction took too long while using std::shuffle

Tags: smart-contract, action

Get the error when I push a action on my contract on the local testnet:

[image]

But if I remove this code from the action I called, there is no problem:

[image]

class urng:

[image]

Does anyone know what caused this?I just want to use a random seed in my contract to shuffle my array.

Comment: Welcome @Lich! It's _much_ better practice to copy & paste (and format) code and error messages instead of  posting images/screenshots. See  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I am asking questions on here for the first time. I will pay attention next time, thank you for your reminder!

Comment: all good, just giving you a head's up. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `urng` class is somehow causing an issue, can you confirm that the following code does or does not work?

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
shuffle (foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
```

Also, I don't know what you are programming, but any random number generated in this way is **not** safe. It will be deterministic and can not be used to protect against people calculating a result for a game in advance or something like this. To learn about how to do random numbers, see [How can I generate random numbers inside a smart contract?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/41/how-can-i-generate-random-numbers-inside-a-smart-contract)

Comment: You are right, I found the cause of the problem while debugging the source code of std::shuffle, I should not return a constant in urng::operator()(), this will cause an infinite loop inside the std::shuffle.
Since eosio.cdt does not support <random>, so I have to implement a URNG myself using the seed provided by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because std::shuffle and also some of the internally used types are making use of multiple iterations.

So depending on the implementation of std:shuffle and the internally used types there are multiple iterations per array-element in your foo-array, which consumes the CPU.

Comment: Yes, I should not return a constant in urng::operator()(), this will cause an infinite loop inside the std::shuffle.